# Hold execution in RoR action until something happend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, timer

I have backend, where user send request from frontend to calculate something. Calculation happen on separate engine, which run with rake command. User have status. And, when calculation is done, user status change to "done", for example.

And, I have to hold execution of some action, until calculation is ended. After user get status "done", I will can move on in action.

I think, I need something like Timer.

Comment: It would be easier to suggest you better solutions if you describe what this rake task do... Is it a rake task from your application? If so, chances are that you don't actually need to call rake directly but through some API or even extract the logic to lib/ and call it both from rake and from your action. For processing jobs I'd recommend something like Sidekiq. For reporting in the client-side you can use either long-polling, regular polling, websocket, sse or similar. Depending on the deployment strategy solutions will differ. Threaded or forked workers?

Comment: Also, if the rake task can take longer than the timeout in your proxy (nginx defaults to 60s for instance), you won't be able to block the request in a regular action. Maybe using live streaming or websockets. If the task will take only a few seconds and you are using a threaded server like Puma, you could use condition variables instead of a timer if you happen to call a Ruby code that can notify your variable. How much time does your rake task take to complete? Why don't you call it with Kernel#system for instance, which will block until it completes?